# How can I get Vaadin roles after SSO login with Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, vaadin

Vaadin application (JAVA: 19, Vaadin: 24.0.5, Spring boot: 3.0.6)
didnt get roles after sso login

I have a vaadin project and want to secure my views. The `MainView.java` should allow access to user with `@RolesAllowed({"ROLE_ADMIN", "ADMIN"})`. After the login through my sso-service, the user is authenticated and got the necessary roles:

```
Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [USERTEST], Granted Authorities: [[OAUTH2_USER, SCOPE_company]], User Attributes: [{userCode=USERTEST, userTeam=T_X, userEmail=user@company.at, userKtksnr=0, roles=[ADMIN, ROLE_ADMIN], principal={authorities=[], details={remoteAddress=127.0.0.1, sessionId=null, tokenValue=H7G7LR-Ghiq5BmPFqcuGrAt5ZxI, tokenType=Bearer, decodedDetails=null}, authenticated=true, userAuthentication={authorities=[], details={remoteAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, sessionId=BFE069B0209E3DADDEFBCFC1BACB23A9}, authenticated=true, principal={userCode=USERTEST, userTeam=T_X, userEmail=user@company.at, userKtksnr=0, roles=[ADMIN, ROLE_ADMIN]}, credentials=null, name=User{userCode='USERTEST', userTeam='T_X', userEmail='user@company.at', userKtksnr=0, roles=[ADMIN, ROLE_ADMIN]}}, clientOnly=false, credentials=, oauth2Request={clientId=company, scope=[company], requestParameters={code=PSVUul, grant_type=authorization_code, scope=company, response_type=code, state=R6czQI2wlFbfNwfqoulg6ckrthGnTS4JJjS7nkdAlg0=, redirect_uri=http://localhost:7060/company/login/oauth2/code/company, client_id=company}, resourceIds=[], authorities=[], approved=true, refresh=false, redirectUri=http://localhost:7060/company/login/oauth2/code/company, responseTypes=[code], extensions={}, refreshTokenRequest=null, grantType=authorization_code}, principal={userCode=USERTEST, userTeam=T_X, userEmail=user@company.at, userKtksnr=0, roles=[ADMIN, ROLE_ADMIN]}, name=User{userCode='USERTEST', userTeam='T_X', userEmail='user@company.at', userKtksnr=0, roles=[ADMIN, ROLE_ADMIN]}}, applicationRoles=ADMIN,ROLE_ADMIN}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=5278B052E19AD339C2CCF1A20E5ACA8D], Granted Authorities=[OAUTH2_USER, SCOPE_company]]]
```

A TestView.java with the annotation `@PermitAll` is working as espected (without authentication redirect to SSO and with authentication View is visible).

But the MainView.java with annotation `@RolesAllowed({"ROLE_ADMIN", "ADMIN"})` the access is always denied:

**Client Application:**

MainView.java

```
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.*;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.PageTitle;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import jakarta.annotation.security.RolesAllowed;

@PageTitle("MainView")
@Route(value = "", layout = MainLayout.class)
@RolesAllowed({"ROLE_ADMIN", "ADMIN"})
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {
    public MainView() {
        H3 title = new H3("Application");
        add(title);
    }
}
```

UiSecurityConfig.java

```java
import com.vaadin.flow.spring.security.VaadinWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class UiSecurityConfig extends VaadinWebSecurity {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/public/**"))
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login() ;
        super.configure(http);
    }
}
```

application.yml

```yaml
server:
  port: 7060
  servlet:
    context-path: /application
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          company:
            client-id: application
            client-secret:
            scope: MAM
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:7060/application/login/oauth2/code/company
        provider:
          company:
            authorization-uri: http://localhost:9090/sso-service/auth/oauth/authorize
            token-uri: http://localhost:9090/sso-service/auth/oauth/token
            user-info-uri: http://localhost:9090/sso-service/auth/user/me
            user-name-attribute: userCode
resourceserver:
  api:
    project:
      url: http://localhost:9090/sso-service/auth/user/me
logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        security: DEBUG
```

**Spring-oauth2-SSO-Application:**

Here is the custom ´UserController´ where ´/user/me´ is called and the User get all the information:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

private QueryUserDataTemplate queryTemplate;

@Autowired
public UserController(QueryUserDataTemplate queryTemplate) {
    this.queryTemplate = queryTemplate;
}

@GetMapping("/user/me")
public User user(Principal principal) {
    User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

    String clientId = ((OAuth2Authentication) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()).getOAuth2Request().getClientId();
    List<String> roleList = queryTemplate.queryForApplicationRoles(user.getSybCode(), clientId);
    if (roleList != null) {
        user.setRoles((Collection) roleList);
    }
    return new UserResult(principal, user.getSybCode(), user.getSybTeam(), user.getSybEmail(), user.getSybKtksnr(), user.getRoles(), user.getAuthorities());
}


public static class UserResult extends User {

    private final Principal principal;

    private UserResult(Principal principal, String username, String sybTeam, String sybEmail, Long sybktksnr,
                       Collection applicationRoles, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(username, sybTeam, sybEmail, sybktksnr, applicationRoles, authorities);
        this.principal = principal;
    }

    public Principal getPrincipal() {
        return principal;
    }
}
```

If you need any other info, please let me know!

EDIT:
DEBUG INFO:

```
Request received for POST '/?v-r=uidl&v-uiId=0':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@24c0d321

servletPath:/
pathInfo:null
headers: 
host: localhost:7060
connection: keep-alive
content-length: 529
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="113", "Chromium";v="113", "Not-A.Brand";v="24"
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
accept: */*
origin: http://localhost:7060
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-dest: empty
referer: http://localhost:7060/mam/
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
cookie: JSESSIONID=F95188E5E420170BFF950B0C8D6BB8C6


Security filter chain: [
  DisableEncodeUrlFilter
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextHolderFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CsrfFilter
  LogoutFilter
  OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter
  OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter
  DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter
  DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  AuthorizationFilter
]
```

Comment: What does `org.springframework.security` logging to DEBUG say?

Comment: Also the toString from your Principal does have the roles you assume (Granted Authoriities); are you missing some mapping for the roles from the access token into your principal?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with missing some mapping? where do i miss it?

Comment: That's not Spring Security DEBUG logs. You have to change your log configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined an OAuth2 client security configuration (OAuth2 login and security based on sessions), but have provided nothing for [authorities mapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/advanced.html#oauth2login-advanced-map-authorities) => the value of the "roles" claim in user-info is not turned into Spring authorities.

Exposing a `GrantedAuthoritiesMapper` bean converting roles to authorities could be enough.

I suggest you read the doc I linked just above and [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials).